# CakePHP3 REST API on public server not working

Tags: cakephp-3.0

I followed this tutorial:

http://www.bravo-kernel.com/2015/04/how-to-build-a-cakephp-3-rest-api-in-minutes/

and on localhost I can get everything to work as expected using Postman, however as soon as I move it to Siteground I get this error:

```
{
"message": "You are not authorized to access that location.",
"url": "/api/customers",
"code": 401
}
```

again it works locally. I also remove the app then used the provided installer to see if that was the issue and that didn't work either. Does anyone know what might be the issue?

**Figured it out:**
I had to add this to the **webroot folder** .htaccess:

```
 RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]
```

Comment: I figured out that I'm creating a bad token, so I am assuming there is a file permission issue.

Comment: Well I chmod my whole app to 755 to and I am now creating a good toke but the error remains.

Comment: Figured it out after reading the docs closer:

Comment: In case authentication does not work like expected, check if queries are executed at all (see BaseAuthenticate::_query($username)). In case no queries are executed check if $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] do get populated by the webserver. If you are using Apache with FastCGI-PHP you might need to add this line to your .htaccess file in webroot:

RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization},L]